# Open set in R^2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm totally stuck at this simple exercise. I want to show that the set $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:y>x^2, |x|<2\}$ is open. I've already drawn the set, but I don't even know how to find the radius for my open disk.

So, for example, if $p=(x_{0}, y_{0})\in S$, and if $y_{0}\ge 4$, then I can clearly pick as a radius $2-x_{0}$. But what happens when $y_{0}\lt 4$? Also, I don't like this approach, it's not elegant and it's very tedious to do case distinction. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Geeze, you're overthinking the problem. is |x| open of closed?

Comment: I guess you meant if |x| < 2 is open. The answer is yes. How can I continue from here?

Comment: Draw the circle X^2 = 2. Is the circle itself, a boundary for y, open or closed?

Comment: The point is that the circle cuts the xy plane into three regions. The area inside the circle, the points on the circle, and the planar area outside the circle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little lost with what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry. my very very bad. I read your attempt and started thinking circles that have nothing to do with this. I should have read the problem and thought for a second. Start off by plotting |x|<2 on the x-axis. Now for the region which is |x|<2 drawn some plots on the graph as to what the function of y would be for y=x^2. Further hint function of y=x^2 is a curve in x-y plane which cuts a section of the plane into three parts.

Answer (score 2):

*I assume you're supposed to solve this by explicitly writing the region as a union of open balls. Otherwise, there are plenty of other ways to show $S$ is open, depending on what you already know - see e.g. Gudson Chou's answer.*

Think in terms of the boundary of the region. Given a point $p=(x_0, y_0)\in S$, we want to know

- How far is $p$ from the parabola $y=x^2$?
- How far is $p$ from the line $x=2$?
- How far is $p$ from the line $x=-2$?

You can find each of these distances algebraically. Call those three distances $D_1(p), D_2(p), D_3(p)$, respectively. Then the best radius you can take is expressible in terms of these - think about how.

Comment: Maybe the minimum of the distances?

Comment: Yup! Now you just have to calculate those distances. (Only one will be at all interesting.)

Comment: D1 would be the most interesting. Assuming that I don't "know" yet what a derivative is, I find it very difficult to calculate the exact value. Another question arises: is that even necessary i.e. calculating the exact value of the distance?

Comment: @Allonsy No, you don't need the exact value - you just need some number which is guaranteed to be *no greater than* that value (so you can undershoot).